# Generate vector of values from closure

Tags: r

This type of thing is easy in F# but I can't figure out how to do it in R. I want to generate a vector with values generated from a closure. In F# it works something like this. The first argument is the number of elements you would want, the second is the iterator for the closure and the last argument is the closure to generate the values. Is something like this possible in R? I use it all the time in F#.

```
result <- GenerateVector(5, n, function(n){
    n*10
})
```

Would result in:

```
result =
10
20
30
40
50
```

Comment: Does it need to have the second argument `n`? For this example it seems totally redundant given the usual R paradigms.

Comment: Not at all. I just need to know what the iterator is. This is just the syntax that F# uses for this kind of thing.

Comment: Also, I presume that the `5` is there to mean `1, 2, ..., 5`

Comment: Correct, the first argument is the number of items I'm wanting to generate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment, if the second argument is not needed (i.e. you don't *need* to specify what the iterator is), then we could write `GenerateVector()` like this:

```
GenerateVector <- function(x, FUN) {
    do.call(FUN, list(seq_len(x)))
}

R> GenerateVector(5, FUN = function(n) {n*10})
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
```

Whether that will work for you more generally will depend on whether `FUN` is a vectorised function (like your example) or not. Of course, you will hit major inefficiencies if you use functions that don't accept vectors, so this is probably not too great an issue.

In general, these things are far easier to write using normal R conventions:

```
R> 1:5 * 10
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
R> foo <- function(n) n * 10
R> foo(1:5)
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
```

All `do.call()` in my example is doing is writing the last two lines of R code above for you.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like `sapply` might do it:

```
sapply(1:5, function(n)10*n)
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
```

The similarity is that `sapply` takes a list as input, applies a function to each element in that list, and returns the result in a list. Since a list is itself a vector, you can do the same with an input vector.

In this example we use the `:` operator to construct a vector sequence.

Comment: You're correct, but it depends what the purpose of the function is, doesn't it?

Comment: Of course (said as much in my Answer). Just pulling your leg given the content of your Dummies book :P